# Code First Table Per Hierarchy error with shared column names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have 3 classes that inherit from an abstract class, all of them are represented by one table in the database using the Table Per Hierarchy method.

There is a property named 'foo' that is shared by two of the concrete classes, but not by the third, therefore it is not included in the abstract class.

Code first migrations tries to create two columns for the shared "foo" property, calling them "foo" and "foo1" even though they are both named "foo" in their respective classes. I edited the migration to delete "foo1" so that only one column named "foo" gets created in the db.

I can create instances of the classes containing the "foo" property with no problem. However, when I attempt to save and persist them to the db I get an error saying "Invalid column name foo1" even though there is absolutely no mention of "foo1" anywhere in my project. It's like Entity framework is still insisting on doing whatever logic the migration originally had even though I changed it before running the migration and creating the table.

So my question is, how can I have two of the same columns in concrete classes that is not shared by their parent class be represented in the database table by only one column?

Comment: Have you tried to introduce yet another class to the hierarchy, one that contains the foo property and the two that also contain it just inherit from the class?

Comment: @WiktorZychla no I have not. I was hoping to avoid that but if that's what I have to do then so be it. Hoping for a different solution though.

Comment: I don't think there are other options, if the obvious renaming colliding properties is also not what you'd like to do.

Comment: using the Column annotation to specify the column name did the trick

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by using the Column annotation in the POCO

```
[Column("foo")]
public string foo { get; set; }
```

Comment: In my case I already had the Column annotation, but forgot the Table annotation above one of my concrete classes.